# How can I detect why a systemd service has stopped?

Tags: systemd

It's status suddenly goes to inactive, no errors nor anything else suspicious from `journalctl -u servicename` nor `systemctl status servicename`

```
Description=Provide audio stream for homeassistant noise detection
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root

Type=simple

ExecStart=/bin/sh /arecord_pipe_ffmpeg.sh                 

TimeoutStopSec=20
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't –– if that script `/arecord_pipe_ffmpeg.sh` doesn't do any logging, systemd nor anything else can't know why it exited.

By the way, not a usual place to put scripts, `/`.